# Unexcpected behavior in numpy when changing values by conditions

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, mask

I have numpy array with the shape (104,107) and values between 0- 0.6 :
[image]

I want to classify the image by three classes:

- Pixels with value larger than 0.25 (high_bord) ->get value 1
- Pixels with value smaller than 0.17 (low_bord)  ->get value 2
- Pixels with value between low_bord and high_bord  -> get value 3

This is the script I have used for the classification:

```py
arr[arr < low_bord] = 1
arr[arr > high_bord] = 2
arr[(arr>=low_bord)&(arr<=high_bord)] = 3
```

that gives me the following results:

[image]

as it can be seen, the minimum value in this case is 2, which could ne interperated as- only 2 conditions were found.
However, I believe this results ar wrong, and when I change the value of the first condition to be -1 , then I get three classes:

```py
arr[arr < low_bord] = -1
arr[arr > high_bord] = 2
arr[(arr>=low_bord)&(arr<=high_bord)] = 3
```

[image]

I have the suspicion that  it has t odo with the order to the conditions (e.g ,after the first condition, the low pixels have values that are larger than the high bord and get value 2? ).
**My end goal is to be able to give each class unique correct value** (and then to color it accordingly)

Comment: how about creating a new_arr = np.zeros_like(arr) and changing its values instead of changing the values of arr inplace? cause 1 is obviously greater than 0.25, so the second line is changing the pixels you changed to 1 in the first line to 2.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Please consider [sharing your own answer and accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @yannziselman I can do this but didn't want to take your credit :)